# How to alter how svg pattern fill is displayed

Tags: svg

So I have a webpage [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2). Under "frame background" there are patterns. When clicked they display in the photo frame. The problem is that some of them seem really blocky. Particularly the last one.

My code for this. 
jquery:

```
    $(" #borders #pattern1").click (function() {
       $(".border").css("fill", "url(#patt1)");
    });
```

svg:

```
    <defs>                              
        <pattern id="patt1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="500">
            <image xlink:href="Images/pattern1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="542" height="774" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
```

I hope this makes sense. If down voting for some reason please give me feedback as to why.

Comment: They seem fine to me. What UA are you using?

Comment: Define "blocky" as you understand it

Comment: Are the images supposed to match up smoothly in a continuous wallpaper?  Some do and some don't -- perhaps the image dimensions don't match the pattern dimensions you're using.

Comment: Yes the patterns are supposed to be continuous and flow smoothly. Where as the last one particularly is made up of repeated rectangles. UA?